# Map Multiple keys for a value

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

Is there any data structure in java or google guava or other libraries which will support mapping mutliple keys to a single value ?

Thanks
Lives

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from pointing several keys to the same object in a regular `Map`.

Comment: A regular `Map` can do that... What do you need that prompted you to ask this question in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

In regular `Map` you can have same values for multiple keys. Only constraint is you cannot have duplicate keys. If you do previous value will be overwritten.

```
    Map<String,String> myMap= new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("A","Test1");
    myMap.put("B","Test1");
```

This is also the reason why `value()` method on `Map` returns `Collection` unlike `keySet()` method which returns `Set`(unique values.)

```
Collection<String> values = myMap.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just regular Map, like HashMap.

```
map.put( 'a' , X );
map.put( 'b' , X );
```

You didn't precised if you want to have every value maped with 2-key pair, or to have single key pointing value X and another key poiting value X also.